# Count frequence, how to take two word each time?

Tags: python

```
["this","example"]:1  , ["is","silly"]:1  ....
```

something like that.
I can handle the case for single word, but how can you access two element and let them become the key?

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
    word_list = f.read().lower()

    unwanted = ['(', ')', '\\', '"', '\'','.',';',':','!']

    for c in unwanted:
        word_list = word_list.replace(c," ")

    words = word_list.split()

    fdic = {}

    for word in words:

        # form dictionary how can you let key be pair of item?
        fdic[word] = fdic.get(word,0) + 1
```

Comment: Can't you consider two words into one single string?

Comment: @v.coder, tuples of words may allow more efficient memory use. Imagine scaling to 3 or 4 consecutive words and needing to store all those combinations as unique strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the list of bigrams using a list comprehension iterating over your original list of words:

```
bigrams = [word_list[i] + " " + wordlist[i+1] for i in range(len(wordlist)-1)]
```

Comment: Or this one: `fdic = {i: 1 for i in [tuple(words[i: i+2]) for i in range(0, len(words), 2)]}`. Note that list cannot be a dict key, so use tuple instead.

Comment: @KevinGuan, unfortunately that gives a count of `1` for every item

Answer (score 0):

you could try following code to get the group first. Then use the tuple to do counting.

```
words = ["This","example","is","silly",".","That","example","is","also","silly","."]

for i in range(0,len(words), 2):
    group = None
    if i+1 < len(words):
        group = (words[i], words[i+1])
    else:
        group = (words[i], )
    print group
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make two words the key on a dictionary converting them into a tuple, a hashable type:

```
words = ["This","example","is","silly","That","example","is","also","silly"]

fdic = {}

for i in range(len(words)-1):
    word = tuple(words[i:i+2])
    fdic[word] = fdic.get(word,0) + 1
print fdic
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest storing the word pairs as a tuple.

```
from collections import defaultdict

content = 'This example is silly. That example is also silly.'.lower()
unwanted = ['(', ')', '\\', '"', '\'','.',';',':','!']

for c in unwanted:
    content = content.replace(c," ")

words = content.split()

fdic = defaultdict(int)

for idx, word in enumerate(words[1:]):
    pair = (words[idx], words[idx + 1])
    fdic[pair] += 1
```

Result:

```
{('is', 'also'): 1,
('example', 'is'): 2,
('also', 'silly'): 1,
('silly', 'that'): 1,
('this', 'example'): 1,
('is', 'silly'): 1,
('that', 'example'): 1}
```

You don't need to use the defaultdict, but it simplifies the process of initializing each new key to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why no one is suggesting to use a Counter - after all it *is* for counting things.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> words = ["This","example","is","silly","That","example","is","also","silly"]
>>> print(Counter(tuple(words[i: i + 2]) for i in range(len(words) - 1)))
Counter({('example', 'is'): 2, ('This', 'example'): 1, ('is', 'silly'): 1, ('is', 'also'): 1, ('That', 'example'): 1, ('also', 'silly'): 1, ('silly', 'That'): 1})
```

You may also like to use extra filtering on words - make lowercase etc.